# return the highest number from object properties value

Tags: javascript

I have the following inside an ajax call:

```
        for (var key in json.rating) {
            var numb = Math.max(json.rating[key]);
        }
        console.log(numb);

"rating":{
"overall": 92,
"atmosphere": 93,
"cleanliness": 94,
"facilities": 89,
"staff": 94,
"security": 92,
"location": 88,
"valueForMoney": 92
},
```

It seems like numb doesn't return the highest number as I thought it would.

It's returning 92

Comment: You're constantly rewriting the number so the number is the last one. To not confuse yourself, declare `var numb = 0;` *before* your loop and use `numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key])` to include the current value in your max calculation.

Comment: Try this: `Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(json.rating).map(function(k) { return json.rating[k]; }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The main problem here is that you are simply iterating object keys and rewriting the key value inside your `numb` variable, because you are passing only one argument to `Math.max()` which is the iterated number.

So you will always get the last iterated value, that explains why you got
   `92`as result.

**Solution:**

In fact you should initialize the `numb` vraiable and always compare it with every iterated value, this is an edited snippet:

```js
var json = {
  "rating": {
    "overall": 92,
    "atmosphere": 93,
    "cleanliness": 94,
    "facilities": 89,
    "staff": 94,
    "security": 92,
    "location": 88,
    "valueForMoney": 92
  }
};

var numb = 0;
for (var key in json.rating) {
  numb = Math.max(json.rating[key], numb);
}
document.write(numb);
```

**Note:**

This assumes that all your values are positive numbers that's why I initialized it to `0`, otherwise just initialize `numb` to `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) takes a sequence of numbers and returns the highest of that sequence.

**In your case:** You call `max()` many times with only a single argument every time, and each time `max()` returns only that argument. So whatever you passed in your last call is the final value of `numb`.

**Solution 1:** Build a list of numbers using your loop, and then call `max()` once and pass that list. However, this iterates twice over your sequence of numbers (Note the use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).)

```
numbers = []
for (var key in json.rating) {
    numbers.push(json.rating[key]);
}
numb = Math.max(...numbers);
console.log(numb);
```

**Solution 2:** Hold the largest value and compare it against the value of the current iteration. This iterates only once over your sequence of numbers.

```
numb = Number.MIN_VALUE;
for (var key in json.rating) {
    numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key]);
}
console.log(numb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start off by declaring numb as the minimum value that you could expect, then when you iterate through your loop, pass the existing value for testing against the current value.

```
    var numb = -999999;
    for( var key in json.rating ) {
      numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key]);
    }
    console.log(numb);
```

Comment: If I want to return the property associated with the highest number? "Staff for example"

Comment: @h2ooooooo, the `Number.MIN_VALUE` return `5e-324` wheras we need a **negative** `Number.MAX_VALUE` with `-1.7976931348623157e+308`.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the max value. one way to do it is:

```
var maxNumber = -Infinity;
for (var key in json.rating) {
    maxNumber = Math.max(maxNumber, json.rating[key]);
}
console.log(maxNumber);
```

this way, you constantly comparing the current value with the saved max value

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var rating = {
"overall": 92,
"atmosphere": 93,
"cleanliness": 94,
"facilities": 89,
"staff": 94,
"security": 92,
"location": 88,
"valueForMoney": 92
}

//get all the values in an array
var allvalues = Object.keys(rating).map(function(key){return rating[key];});

// get the max value from the array
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, allvalues));
```

Comment: This iterates *twice* over the sequence of items: once to build a list of all numbers, and a second time to find the max of that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var rating = {
      "overall": 92,
      "atmosphere": 93,
      "cleanliness": 94,
      "facilities": 89,
       "staff": 94,
       "security": 92,
       "location": 88,
       "valueForMoney": 92
 };

 var arr = Object.keys( rating ).map(function ( key ) { return rating[key]; });
 var min = Math.min.apply( null, arr );
 var max = Math.max.apply( null, arr );

 console.log( 'Min value: ' + min + ', max value: ' + max );
```

Comment: This does not work, because [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) still compares only a single value which is the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the keys and reduce the value to max.

```js
var rating = { atmosphere: 85, cleanliness: 91, facilities: 91, staff: 85, security: 94, location: 78, valueForMoney: 85 },
    hi = Object.keys(rating).reduce(function (r, k) { 
        return Math.max(r, rating[k]);
    }, -Number.MAX_VALUE);

document.write(hi);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you forgot to declare "var numb=0", and before you use your loop, please change "Math.max(json.rating[key])" into "Math.max(numb,json.rating[key])"
then, it will be proceed appropriately